# Storing binary data in the __DATA__ handle

Tags: perl

In a module I need an image data (BMP) for some [Imager::Search](https://metacpan.org/pod/Imager::Search) operation. The following works,

```
my $pattern = Imager::Search::Pattern->new(
     driver => 'Imager::Search::Driver::BMP24',
     file   => 'test.bmp', #load the image from a file
);
```

The **image** (`test.bmp`) is constant for me, so want store it directly in the source code as

```
my $image = ... the image data ... ;
```

or in the `__DATA__` section.

What is an recommended method storing binary data (such `test.bmp`) in the `__DATA__`? (2.3kb).

Comment: Why? I can think of various interesting ways this might fail if you actually store **binary** data as opposed to just putting the hex presentation. See [unpack](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#unpack).

Comment: Use Base64 encoding, and the core module Mime::Base64 to decode it.  This avoids the pitfalls of trying to place raw binary data directly in a source code file.

Comment: I think it would be much better to keep the image as a separate bitmap file, but you might want to take a look at [`MIME::Base64`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Base64) which will allow you to encode the binary data as printable ASCII characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably wouldn't want to deal with the headaches of storing raw binary data in a source file, but that doesn't mean that you can't still use a solution that stores the image in the `__DATA__` segment.  You would just encode it in a plain-text format first, such as Base64.

[Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/) is an example of this sort of thing.  With [Mojolicious::Lite](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite) it is possible to embed templates and other static content in segments within the `__DATA__` section.  And Base64-encoded data is one possibility, as documented in [Mojolicious::Guides::Tutorial#Static Files](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Tutorial#Static-files).

The point to this is to demonstrate that this type of approach is sometimes used.  If you wanted to implement a solution that uses this approach, you would use the core Perl module [MIME::Base64](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Mime%3A%3ABase64&mode=all).  Here's an example where some arbitrary plain old text is stored in Base64 format, and retrieved for use.  However, since Base64 encoding can be used on binary data, this example could be adapted to store an image instead.

```
use MIME::Base64;

my $foo = do {
    local $/ = undef;
    decode_base64(<DATA>);
};

print "<<$foo>>\n";

__DATA__
SnVzdCBhbm90aGVyClBlcmwgaGFja2VyLA==
```

Comment: Really nice answer (opposed to the "don't do it" like unhelpful comments). Does exactly for what I'm looking. Thank you very much.

Comment: Correct, the user would encode binary data as base64, and then place *that* in the `__DATA__` section.  It's easily decoded, and the MIME::Base64 module comes with Perl.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, [@DavidO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28954404/100754) is a correct answer. You could also use hex instead of base64.

For this, first append the hex dump of the image to the module source file. You can do this, for example, using `xxd`:

```
$ xxd -ps /path/to/image >> lib/My/Module.pm
```

assuming your module file ends with `__DATA__` or `__END__`.

You can then convert the hex dump back to binary. This being Perl, there are, of course, various ways of doing this ... not all equally good, including the following:

```
sub load_data {
    my $bin;
    while (my $line = <DATA>) {
        $line =~ s/\s+\z//;
        $bin .= pack 'H*', $line;
    }
    $bin;
}
```

or, if you want to slurp:

```
my $png = pack 'H*',
          map { s{\s+}{}g; $_ }
          do { local $/; scalar <DATA> }
;
binmode STDOUT;
print $png;
```

Of course, if your `perl` is 5.14+, then you can take advantage of the `s///r`:

```
my $png = pack 'H*', map s{\s+}{}gr, do { local $/; scalar <DATA> };
```

More detail in my blog post "[Include image data in your Perl script or module](http://www.nu42.com/2015/03/include-image-data-perl-module.html)".

See also [perldoc pack](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#pack-TEMPLATE-LIST) and [perldoc hex](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#hex).